# How to fetch metadata of a private vimeo video?

Tags: php, laravel-5, vimeo

I am working on a laravel project which requires vimeo API.

I have generated client and secretkey on developer.vimeo.com, but it seems to be not able to use them. Official vimeo php library does no guide about it.

I just need to fetch information of private video like thumbnail and duration.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
   /* You may want to use oEmbed discovery instead of hard-coding the oEmbed endpoint. */
    $oembed_endpoint = 'http://vimeo.com/api/oembed';    
    // Grab the video url from the url, or use default
    $video_url = ($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'http://vimeo.com/7100569';    
    // Create the URLs
    $json_url = $oembed_endpoint . '.json?url=' . rawurlencode($video_url) . '&width=640';
    $xml_url = $oembed_endpoint . '.xml?url=' . rawurlencode($video_url) . '&width=640';

    // Curl helper function
    function curl_get($url) {
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $return = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $return;
    }    
    // Load in the oEmbed XML
    $oembed = simplexml_load_string(curl_get($xml_url));    

    /* An alternate approach would be to load JSON,
        then use json_decode() to turn it into an array.*/ 
     ?>



 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vimeo PHP oEmbed Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1><?php echo $oembed->title ?></h1>
    <h2>by <a href="<?php echo $oembed->author_url ?>"><?php echo $oembed->author_name ?></a></h2>

    <?php echo html_entity_decode($oembed->html) ?>

</body>
</html>
```

try this also

**https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-vimeo**

Comment: its not what i asked for i need to know how to fetch the data of a private video any example code tht might helpful.